# How can I prove a truncated hash fuction need not be collision resistant?

Tags: hash

Let $H : \{0, 1\}^∗ \mapsto \{0, 1\}^ n$ be a collision-resistant hash function. Define $H_0(M) = H(M)\mathbin\|0^{n−10}$. That is, $H_0$ appends ($n − 10$) zeros to the output of $H$. Clearly $H_0$ is collision resistant.

Now let $H_{00}$ be the result of truncating the output of $H_0$
to $n$ bits. The question is to show that if the truncation is done incorrectly, then $H_{00}$ will not be collision resistant. In other words, a truncated collision resistant function need not be collision resistant.

Comment: Welcome to cryptography. I've edited your dump with $\LaTeX$ and here we have MathJax, too. Please check the edits. Is this a homework question? In Cryptography.SE we only provide hints for such questions, and this seems so. **Hint:** What if you remove the first part from $H_0(M)$?

Comment: Yes, but the question said H00 truncates H0 to n bits, so the H0(M) part can not be totally removed.

Comment: $H_{00} = H(M)|_{10} \mathbin\| 0^{n-10}$ you have 10 bit unkown. Which makes only little search?

Comment: Hint: What is $H_{00}$ with respect to $H$?  And what does that become if instead one defines $H_{00}$ to keep the last $n$ bits?

Comment: H00 contains less distinguishable bits than H, but how can I prove it's not collision resistant with fewer bits than the collision resistant one?

Comment: Consider SHA-256 as H then in $H_{00}$ you will only have 10 bit output of the SHA-256 and the rest is all zeros. There is no need to distinguish! Just get $2^5$ values hash them then you will have collision with 50% probability by the birthday paradox.